# characteristic polynomial of an endomorphism of on $\mathcal{O}_X$-module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I've seen several times people looking at the characteristic polynomial of some

$f \in \mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{E})$

where $\mathcal{E}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module on let's say some smooth projective algebraic variety $X$ over a field $k$. I'm not sure I understand what does it means. For instance, where are the coefficients of this polynomial? Are they in k?

Thanks

Comment: Is $\mathcal{E}$ a locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite rank?  If so, then the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X$.  The `$r^{\text{th}$` coefficient is simply the trace of the induced endomorphism $\bigwedge^r(f)$ of $\bigwedge^r \mathcal{E}$.

Comment: Yes, I assume $\mathcal{E}$ is locally free of finite rank. One interesting case is when you have a logarithmic connection $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{E} \otimes \Omega^1(\log D)$ and you look at the residue $Res_{D_i} \nabla \in \mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{O}_{D_i}}(\mathcal{E}_{| D_i})$ at some irreducible component of the normal crossing divisor $D$. What can be said in that case? 